# redirect after accessing external url, if I don't have access of that external url

Tags: php, redirect

Lets say I have two files locally hosted **page_1.php** & **page_2.php**.

I am trying to do that if user visits **page_1.php** it redirects first to *www.example.com*, then after few seconds it redirects to **page_2.php**.

Here is what I've tried.

```
header('refresh:3; url=http://example.com');
header('location: page2.php');
```

> Note: www.example.com is not locally hosted. So I can't place 'header: location' there.

Comment: That is of course impossible.

Comment: When you redirect your visitor to an url (with refresh or location or a link) the user left your page. Than you could not send him to an other page after that, because he is at your page ("page2.php", in your case). The only why you could handle it is to open your "example.com" in an iFrame and set the `refresh` function to your "page2.php" page.

Comment: once you redirect a user away from your site, you lose any control over them. Their browser is connecting to the other site, not yours. Your second header command is completely ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you load the pages using iframes and jquery?

Html:

```
<iframe id="first-iframe" src="https://www.first-domain.com/"></iframe>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#first-iframe").delay(5000).attr('src', 'https://www.second-domain.com/');
```

This way you can show as many pages as you want.